# How to improve the performance when doing rehash?

Tags: algorithm, hashtable

At some point we need to increase the size of hash, and normally we just rehash, which leads to re-constructure of the whole hash.

Is there any better solution so that when we increase the size, we don't need to re-construct the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

You could use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extendible_hashing, although AFAIK it is used mostly for on-disk databases.

There are also general methods for smoothing out some amortised costs. Starting points for this would be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_and_dynamic_data_structures and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamization. One application of this to hash tables would be to always keep two tables, one of size N and one of size 2N or so. When the smaller overflows, start creating a table of size 4N, but don't populate it straight away - populate it incrementally while using the table of size 2N. By the time the table of size 2N is full, the table of size 4N should be ready. For the special case of hash tables, extendible hashing should be better.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you re-hash, there's nothing that says you need to actually re-hash. In fact all that you *actually* need to do is re-mod (i.e. shift everything's position).

If you cache the hash (hehe, sounds like the start of a dr. seuss book) then you only need to compute it once. So store the hash along with the actual data, and that will save you from needing to calculate the hash again in the future. However I'm assuming that you're not already doing this, you didn't exactly explain the current process.

```
// Store these instead of the data directly. This assumes immutable data.
struct hashable_item
{
    data dat;
    int32 hash;
}
```